# Aggregate value error in system verilog

Tags: system-verilog, vga

I am working on a project and have encountered a problem with one of my modules.
I am trying to add offsets to 11 bits input from another model and output them to vga controller.
My inputs are declared like so -

```
input   logic signed  Player_TLX [10:0],     //Current Player Top Left X pos
input   logic signed  Player_TLY [10:0],    //Current Player Top Left Y pos
```

and the calculation I am trying to do are -

```
            if (Fire && !In_Air) begin //Projectile Launch
                    topLeftY_FixedPoint <= (Player_TLY + Player_Height)*FIXED_POINT_MULTIPLIER ;
                    topLeftX_FixedPoint <= Player_TLX + Player_Half_Width ;
                    In_Air <= TRUE ;
                    Enemy_Hit <= FALSE;
            end
```

Where player height, width and the multiplier are constants.
This lines give me the error -

```
Error (10686): SystemVerilog error at Projectile_moveCollision.sv(65): Player_TLY has an aggregate value
Error (10686): SystemVerilog error at Projectile_moveCollision.sv(66): Player_TLX has an aggregate value
```

I have tried using local parameters for the calculations but got similar error ,
is there a way to make such calculations?
am I using the wrong data type for this?
help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the ranges in the declaration in the wrong place. You had an unpacked array of 11 single bits (an aggregate). You want a packed array of 11-bits (an integral)

```
input   logic signed  [10:0] Player_TLX,     //Current Player Top Left X pos
input   logic signed  [10:0] Player_TLY,    //Current Player Top Left Y pos
```